# Is Gringotts really the only worldwide wizarding bank?

Tags: harry-potter, economics, gringotts

In the first Harry Potter book, Hagrid tells Harry that Gringotts is *the only* bank:

> ‘They didn’ keep their gold in the house, boy! Nah, first stop fer us
>   is Gringotts. Wizards’ bank. Have a sausage, they’re not bad cold –
>   an’ I wouldn’ say no teh a bit o’ yer birthday cake, neither.’
>
> ‘Wizards have banks?’
>
> ‘Just the one. Gringotts. Run by goblins.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Chapter 5: *Diagon Alley*.</sub>

In the second one, we learn that Gringotts has people working in others places of the world:

> Bill was the oldest Weasley brother. He and the next brother, Charlie,
>   had already left Hogwarts. Harry had never met either of them, but
>   knew that Charlie was in Romania, studying dragons, and Bill in Egypt,
>   working for the wizards’ bank, Gringotts.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter 4: *At Flourish and Blotts*.</sub>

It has been suggested on this very website that there is probably more than one currency in Harry Potter's wizarding world: [Are the wizard coins in the Harry Potter books international?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33813/are-the-wizard-coins-in-the-harry-potter-books-international). (Personally, I'm of the opinion that Rowling used a hyperbole in the passage discussed in that question).

---

So, was **Hagrid exaggerating?** Was he referring **just to the United Kingdom?** Is Gringotts really ***the one and only* bank on Earth**? And, more importantly, **is there any canon answer that supports either hypothesis?**

---

**Possible answer:** https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50088/23401

Comment: "Oh dear, maths."

Comment: There's only one bank mentioned. It's described as the only bank in the wizarding world. That's about it.

Comment: I suppose it could be a brach? One bank, multiple stores?

Comment: @MacCooper I also think that would be the case, but I can't find any canon source.

Comment: You think goblins would go for such a thing as *competition*?  Really?!  Much more money to be made as a monopoly...

Comment: @Moo that's an excellent point.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Why isn't there ever any mention of the Americas in Harry Potter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/why-isnt-there-ever-any-mention-of-the-americas-in-harry-potter). The question is more broadly focused, but specifically mentions Gringott and whether or not it is the only bank. [Zibbobz' answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50088/5184) specifically addresses this.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm aware of that question, and I agree that that particular answer may suit this question. However, the questions are completely different.

Comment: Dupes are defined by the questions OR the answers provided.

Comment: You can read discussion about the criteria [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3194/5184), [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3684/5184), [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3610/5184) (and probably half a dozen other conversations).

Comment: @phantom42 thanks. I couldn't find anything specific in the help section before writing the question.

Answer (score 7):

Bill is referred to as going to Egypt with Gringott's - the obvious assumption is that there's one "bank organisation" with multiple branches, one of which is in London.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some companies send their employees in a collaborative work with another company. He could easily have been working both for Gringotts and the Egyptian National Bank or whatever.

Comment: He was working as a curse breaker in Egypt. That doesn't necessarily mean Gringotts' has a branch there, only that there's known cursed tombs containing treasures there.

Comment: Also, Gringotts probably has a monopoly *enforced by law* in Britain. That monopoly may not exist in every country in which Gringotts has a footprint. In other words, in some countries, Gringotts may exist, but have the competition they don't have in Britain.