# How do wizards amass their wealth?

Tags: harry-potter

How do wizards amass their gold, do they conjure it?, or is it  inherited, can't they just magic it, how does finance work In the wizard in community

Comment: So many questions, so many dupes.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/rich-wizards-poor-muggles?rq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157613/why-dont-poor-wizards-like-the-weasleys-use-magic-to-improve-their-possessions?rq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-did-harrys-parents-get-all-of-their-money-from and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95165/why-cant-wizards-create-precious-metals?rq=1

Comment: This is a lot of questions in one, and there are answers to all of them.  You should probably start with [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/rich-wizards-poor-muggles?rq=1) (also linked by Valorum above).